# C++ Object pointer exercise

Tags: c++, pointers

Hi i'm new to C++ with knowledge of C. I'm trying to learn object pointers and trying patterns on C++.
I have 2 classes and trying to learn memento. First is manager which holds my object's dynamic array.

Manager.h :

```
#ifndef MANAGER_H
#define MANAGER_H
#include "MyObject.h"

class Manager
{
    public:
        Manager();
        ~Manager();
        MyObject *objArray;
        int _top;
        MyObject topObj();
        void addObj(MyObject newObj);
};

#endif // MANAGER_H
```

Manager.cpp :

```
#include "Manager.h"

Manager::Manager()
{
    objArray = NULL;
    _top = -1;
}

Manager::~Manager()
{
    delete[] objArray;
}

MyObject Manager::topObj()
{
    return objArray[_top]; //Will throw error if empty
}

void Manager::addObj(MyObject newObj)
{
    MyObject *newArray = new MyObject[++_top]();
    for(int i=0; i<_top; i++){
        newArray[i] = objArray[i];
    }
    newArray[_top] = newObj;
    objArray = newArray;
}
```

and in my main

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Manager *mptr = new Manager();
    MyObject *optr = new MyObject(); 
    mptr->addObj(*optr); //won't work 
    //changing object's properties
    mptr->addObj(*optr);
    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't work, when i try addObj method it stops working, i couldn't find anything wrong in it, would you mind telling me where is my mistake

Comment: This code has so many broken assumptions and patterns in it that I see little value in fixing it. Instead buy a better, modern book, read it and rewrite the thing

Comment: What do you mean by stops working? Do you get any output? Errors? Crash?

Comment: _top has initial value of -1. In addObj, you increase that by one and then attempt to create new array with size 0. Obviously nothing will be added to such array. If you want to add something to array[0], size of array has to be at least 1.

Comment: @BrokenFrog: Are you getting any compilation errors?

Comment: @Ville yes you are right thanks for the answer it fixed the problem would accept your answer if you put it

Comment: @Sumeet no compilation error just a crash but fixed it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First line in function `Manager::addObj` is wrong, you want to do:

```
MyObject *newArray = new MyObject[++_top];
```

Also, not sure what you mean that throwing an error (comment in function `Manager::topObj`). If you think that an exception will be thrown if `_top` is -1, you are mistaken. You will get an access violation. It would be good if you were to provide more details about the error (crashes) you are experiencing.

Comment: Program crashed in the main.cpp I didn't test the empty case yet thought it would throw out of bounds error like in java